# Can't run Flask application under Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've been having quite a few issues with running a basic Flask application under my Centos server, Apache and the mod_wsgi module (https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)

I have setup a virtualenv under /var/www/html/flask and installed Flask (under the virtualenv), in this Flask dir I have 2 files:

yourapplication.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/var/www/html/flask/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flask')

from yourapplication import app as application
```

hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My virtual host looks like:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so

#due to centos permissions
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName flask.mydomain.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess yourapplication threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flask/yourapplication.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/flask>
        WSGIProcessGroup yourapplication
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I navigate to flask.mydomain.com I get a 500 error. Apache logs shows the following:

> - mod_wsgi (pid=8889): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/flask/yourapplication.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python
>     module.
> - mod_wsgi (pid=8889): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/flask/yourapplication.wsgi'.
> - Traceback (most recent call last):
> - File "/var/www/html/flask/yourapplication.wsgi", line 1, in      from yourapplication import app as application
> - ImportError: No module named yourapplication

I'm running under CentOS release 6.7 (Final), Installed Python 2.7 and started my virtualenv under that version (virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7) Centos comes with Python 2.6 as default, but I did not think it would be wise to just replace it with a new version)

Comment: it is clear that you are trying to import app from file named yourapplication but your file name is hello.py. just change the line `from yourapplication import app as application` to `from hello import app` and it should work.

Comment: Ahhh... Of course. Big brain fart on this end. Thank you for your help, I'm now getting a ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so: undefined symbol: _PyUnicodeUCS2_AsDefaultEncodedString in my logs, time for some more googling.